# SmartGWT, Spring, Hibernate and Gilead

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt, smartgwt, gilead

I'm writing GWTSmart application using the free version. On the client side I have a grid with RestDataSource that make request to my Servlet. I read  startrow, endrow ... parameters and decide what to read from database using JDBC (MySQL). With result data I make (manual) JSON data and return it to the client side. And it Works ;)

But I decided to look for libraries that can make it easy to write server side of the code.

I'm not sure what [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/), [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/) are for ... can you give me some sort of description and tell me how can they help me (if they can)

And do you know other libraries that can be useful?

P.S. In new in JavaEE Development

Answer (score 4):

Using SmartGWT with datasources can be a pain if you are not using their paid version. Basically because of the lack of documentation on how to integrate Spring and GWT RPC code to the existing datasource format.

I was able to manage some workarounds, using clientOnly Datasources and setTestData, passing A ListGridRecord object as Array of Values.

Check the Country Grids, they use it the same way.

The problem is that you need to compose an array of data and pass them to the component, not very friendly and very code consuming.

I am also looking for an alternative and will get back to you once I find it.

Cheers